# How to copy data of html formatted cell instead of markup

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have some cells in Handsontable, that are displayed using "html" renderer. When I copy these cells and paste them in Excel, I get html content instead of data. Is there a way to display cells as they are, and get their value when copying ?

**JSFiddle example:**
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/gng4wqzy/)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var
    data = [
      {
        title: "Title 1",
        description: "<div style='text-align:right'>148</div>"
      },
      {
        title: "Title 2",
        description: "<div style='text-align:right'>2002</div>"
      }
    ],
    container1,
    hot1;

    container1 = document.getElementById('example1');
        hot1 = new Handsontable(container1, {
        data: data,
        colWidths: [200, 200],
        colHeaders: ["Title", "Description"],
        columns: [
           {data: "title", renderer: "html"},
           {data: "description", renderer: "html"}
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: then you have to access clipboard modified it accordingly i think

Comment: Unfortunately this is the intended behavior so if you'd like to copy the displayed values rather than the actual value of the cells, you'll have to modify the copy/paste plugin or capture the key combination and pass it in the modified version of your data. If you'd like to copy paste the entire table instead, you could think of adding an "export to csv" button which is quite easy to do in JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try converting your input data into json format and have a custom renderer which displays the value from json. Add a toString property to the data which will return exactly what you want to get copied.

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mpusarla/gng4wqzy/6/

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var item1 = {};
  item1.title = "Title 1 ";
  item1.description = {};
  item1.description.text = "Desc 1";
  item1.description.toString = function() {
    return 'Updated Desc for 1';
  }

  var item2 = {};
  item2.title = "Title 2";
  item2.description = {};
  item2.description.text = "Desc 2";

  item2.description.toString = function() {
    return 'Updated Desc for 2 ';
  }

  var data = [];
  data.push(item1);
  data.push(item2);
  var container1, hot1;

  function customRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    td.innerHTML = '<div style="text-align:right">' + value.text;
  }

  container1 = document.getElementById('example1');
  hot1 = new Handsontable(container1, {
    data: data,
    colWidths: [200, 200],
    colHeaders: ["Title", "Description"],
    columns: [{
      data: "title",
      renderer: "text"
    }, {
      data: "description",
      renderer: customRenderer
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
</style><!-- Ugly Hack due to jsFiddle issue --> <script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script> <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
```

```html
<div id="example1" class="hot handsontable"></div>
```